# Playing sound with JavaScript (oninput)

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to play a sound everytime you enter something into a text box. My code is:

```js
var snd = new Audio('http://www.soundjig.com/pages/soundfx/beeps.php?mp3=beep1.mp3');

function click(){
snd.play();
}

function intro2(){
  alert("OK!");
  }
```

```html
<input id="name" onchange="intro2()" oninput="click()">
```

As you can see, the onchange works, but the oninput does not....

JSFiddle: [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/6mz3hkg3/)

I don't know why this doesn't work.... Can you help?

Sorry if this is a bad question; I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) event will be triggered when the value changes on `input` tag. It does not trigger when you click on `input`.

For testing, do type a text on input and your `click()` function will be triggered and played the audio.

**OR**

If you want to play the audio with `click` event on input then you can attach the `click` event something like.

```
<input id="name" onchange="intro2()" onclick="click()">
```

Comment: I did test this, but for some reason, the sound does not work.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Apparently, I had my script placed in the wrong place of the HTML document. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you wanted. Let me know if I need to change it.

```js
var snd = new Audio('http://www.soundjig.com/pages/soundfx/beeps.php?mp3=beep1.mp3');
document.getElementById('name').oninput = function() {
  snd.currentTime = 0;
  snd.play();
};
```

```html
<input id="name">
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks!